# Oracle function returning custom type is not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have an issue with my code in PL/SQL.

I'm creating a function that should return custom type defined as:

```
create TYPE rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_table_type AS TABLE OF RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_type;

create TYPE rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_type AS OBJECT (
  REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME VARCHAR2(32),
  MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS DATE,
  MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE DATE
);
```

Function DDL is:

```
create or replace FUNCTION RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_func RETURN RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_table_type PIPELINED IS
query_string VARCHAR2(32000);
result_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
CURSOR query_usr IS select username from dba_users where (username like 'RMAN%TSM' or username like 'RMAN%CV') and account_status = 'OPEN' order by 1;
i number;
REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME VARCHAR2(32);
MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS DATE;
MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
i:=0;
query_string := '';
FOR usr IN query_usr LOOP
REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME:=substr(usr.username, 6, 8);
IF i=0 THEN
query_string := 'select '''||REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME||''', trunc(sysdate-min(completion_time)), min(completion_time) from '||usr.username||'.bs where incr_level=0 ';
i:=i+1;
ELSE
query_string := query_string||'union all select '''||REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME||''', trunc(sysdate-min(completion_time)), min(completion_time) from '||usr.username||'.bs where incr_level=0 ';
END IF;
END LOOP;
query_string := query_string||'order by 1';
OPEN result_cursor FOR query_string;
LOOP
FETCH result_cursor INTO REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME,MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE;
EXIT WHEN result_cursor%NOTFOUND;
PIPE ROW (RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_type(REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME,MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE));
END LOOP;
CLOSE result_cursor;
RETURN;
END;
```

Everything is compiled properly but, when I try to select function result, I got below error:

`select * from table(RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_func);`

> ORA-00942: tabella o vista inesistente ORA-06512: a
> "RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_FUNC", line 22
> 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I tried to put in output query_string and result is correct, so I think the issue is within OPEN result_cursor ... block.

This is very strange because I have other functions defined same way and they are ok.

Can you please help understand where is the point?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle complains about table (or view) that doesn't exist.

There are two select statements in that code:

- one fetches data from `dba_users` - do you have privileges to do that? Note that this is a function, a **named** PL/SQL procedure; if you acquired privileges on `dba_users` via **role**, that won't work - you'll have to grant them **directly**
- another one presumes that there's `bs` table in each schema whose username is being fetched via cursor

  - question 1: are you sure that such a table exists?
  - question 2: do you have privileges to access these tables from your current user?

  Answers should help you decide what to do.

According to error line number (22), I'd put my bet on problem(s) with the `bs` table.

Comment: Hi, query_string is built properly. If I try to output it, it's populated with expected values, so the point is not about access to dba_users and bs tables :(

Comment: It was related to permissions with bs tables, I fixed it by granting select privilege for all bs tables (as you pointed, select worked outside function, but it didn't work within function because of privileges inherited via role). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have privileges to see all the tables then:

1. In Oracle, if you use unquoted identifiers then Oracle will implicitly convert the identifier to upper-case. Therefore, if you read a value from `dba_users` that is a lower- or mixed-case identifier and then use it unquoted in a `SELECT` query then it will be implicitly converted to upper-case and the user with the incorrect case will not be found (or worse, you will find an incorrect user).
2. Not relevant to your problem but still a bug with your code, if there are multiple rows being returned from your function and you use the query:

   ```sql
   select *
   from   table(RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_func)
   where  ROWNUM = 1;
   ```

   Then the function will be terminated as soon as sufficient rows have been read (i.e. without reading all the values from the cursor) and the second cursor will not be closed. To handle this you need to catch the `NO_DATA_NEEDED` exception and explicitly close the cursor.

With quoted identifiers and catching the `NO_DATA_NEEDED` exception:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_func
  RETURN RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_table_type PIPELINED
IS
  query_string VARCHAR2(32000) := NULL;
  CURSOR query_usr IS
    select username
    from   dba_users
    where  (username like 'RMAN%TSM' or username like 'RMAN%CV')
    and    account_status = 'OPEN'
    order by 1;
    
  result_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  i number := 0;
  REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME VARCHAR2(32);
  MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS DATE;
  MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
  FOR usr IN query_usr LOOP
    REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME:=substr(usr.username, 6, 8);
    IF i=0 THEN
      query_string := 'select '''||REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME||''', trunc(sysdate-min(completion_time)), min(completion_time) from "'||usr.username||'".bs where incr_level=0 ';
      i:=i+1;
    ELSE
      query_string := query_string
                   || 'union all select '''||REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME||''', trunc(sysdate-min(completion_time)), min(completion_time) from "'||usr.username||'".bs where incr_level=0 ';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF query_string IS NOT NULL THEN
    query_string := query_string||'order by 1';

    OPEN result_cursor FOR query_string;
    LOOP
      FETCH result_cursor INTO REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME,MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE;
      EXIT WHEN result_cursor%NOTFOUND;

      PIPE ROW (RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_type(REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME,MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE));
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE result_cursor;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN
    CLOSE result_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, access to all tables (dba_tables + all bs tables) is guaranteed because if I try to output query_string, I can see that it's populated as expected. Anyway I can't see the changes about point 1 :(

Comment: @S.Viscomi `from "'||usr.username||'".bs`

Comment: Same result: `select * from table(RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_FUNC);` ORA-00942: tabella o vista inesistente
ORA-06512: a "RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_FUNC", line 20
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: There is also a potential SQL injection bug if someone creates a user with a username containing single quotes. I've not addressed that bug in the answer on the assumption that: (a) your usernames are probably not generated by the user so avenues for exploitation are going to be limited; (b) if you use quoted identifiers then the main exploitation vector is going to be poisoning `REG_DB_UNIQUE_NAME` which is restricted to 8 characters long and that is probably only sufficient to force a syntax error rather than SQL injection attacks; and (c) its not related to the current problem.

Comment: @S.Viscomi Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(query_string);` to output the generated query to the console and the run that query as the user that the procedure is running as and see whether it works.

Comment: Already done, query generated works returning 3 fields as expected.

Comment: @S.Viscomi Assuming you have run the query as the correct user and the query works. Now comment out the code for dynamic query generation in the function and put the hard-coded query in. Does the function generate an error with the hard-coded SQL statement? If it did and the query worked when run directly by that user and did not work when run in the function then see Littlefoot's answer about it not working when the permission is granted by a role.

Comment: I cloned my function starting from other functions that work and that are using same initial cursor. So RCATPROD user can access to dba_users through function without any issues. Moreover I'm trying to execute `select * from table(RCATPROD.RC_RMAN_GUARANTEED_BACKUPS_FUNC);` with sysdba user.

Comment: @S.Viscomi You may run the query as `sysdba` but the function is owned by `RCATPROD` and will run as that user and if `RCATPROD` cannot see those tables then they will not be found (even if `sysdba` can see those tables). You can try specifying the [`invokers_rights_clause` for the function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html#GUID-B71BC5BD-B87C-4054-AAA5-213E856651F2__BABFIIBA) and setting it to `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` so that the function is run as if it is the current user (rather than as the definer).

Comment: I did another test: I generated query_string (populated as expected), then I executed it manually logged as RCATPROD (not sysdba), and it worked again. So the issue is not about accessing tables. Issue is about block `OPEN result_cursor FOR query_string;
LOOP
FETCH result_cursor INTO MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE;
EXIT WHEN result_cursor%NOTFOUND;
PIPE ROW (RCATPROD.rc_rman_guaranteed_backups_type(MIN_GUARANTEED_DAYS,MIN_GUARANTEED_DATE));
END LOOP;
--CLOSE result_cursor;`

Comment: It was related to permissions with bs tables, I fixed it by granting select privilege for all bs tables (as Littlefoot pointed, select worked outside function, but it didn't work within function because of privileges inherited via role). Thank you very much for your support!